# Multiple GLcanvas with different context, can't setCurrent() in hidden panel, how to modify scene?

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets

I am implementing an application with two panels containing a GLcanvas each one of them. The panels represent two types of view of the same thing and their visibility its alternated by a selection button. In the paint event I check if they are visible in order to setCurrent() that canvas and paint it.

The problem comes when I want to modify something in the two scenes at the same time. For example a texture change in an object in both of the scenes. I cannot setCurrent() a hidden panel and the glMethods used are going to be applied just in the visible scene.

Am I forced to set visible the other panel to make the modifications and then come back?
What is the best approach to handle multiple panels with multiple contexts not always visible all at once?

! The two scenes have more than a different camera placement, that is why I use different contexts. (What is a sphere in one canvas is a cube in the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest wxWidgets trunk you can call `SetCurrent()` when the window is not shown on screen because its parent is hidden (the window itself still needs to be shown though), see [this change](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/changeset/76644). Unfortunately there is no good solution if you are using a released version, the best I can advise is to store the modification that you need to do in some internal queue and then apply them all once the window does become visible, but this is quite clumsy, of course. It would probably be better to just update your local wx sources...